# About the definible sets $L_\alpha$

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal number. Is that true that $\alpha$ = $\beth_\alpha $ is equivalent to the statement $|L_\alpha|=|R_\alpha|$, where $L_\alpha $ is the $\alpha$-th stage of the constructible hierarchy?

Comment: What is $R_\alpha$?

Comment: Ra is definined by transfinite recursión to bet the potence set of R(a-1) and the limit if a is limit

Comment: What is the base case for $\alpha=0$?

Comment: L(0)= 0 is the base

Comment: Ok thanks, now I get it. Is $R_0:=L_0$ and $R_{\alpha+1}:=\mathcal P (R_\alpha)$

Comment: @Julio, what is a potence set? Is $R_\alpha$ just the family of all sets having hereditarily cardinality less than $\aleph_\alpha$?

Comment: @user18921: $R_\alpha$ is often denoted by $V_\alpha$. You're talking about $H(\aleph_\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every infinite ordinal $\alpha$ it holds:

$|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ and $|R_\alpha|=\beth_{\omega+\alpha}$. If $\alpha$ is a $\beth$-fixed point then $\alpha=\omega+\alpha=\beth_\alpha$ (the addition there is ordinal addition). And it follows that equality holds.

On the other hand, if $\alpha$ is not a $\beth$-fixed point, then $\alpha\neq\beth_\alpha$. Clearly $|\alpha|\leq\beth_\alpha$, so in that case $|L_\alpha|<|R_\alpha|$.

---

To see that $|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|$ note that $L_\omega$ is countable, and $|L_{\alpha+1}|=\aleph_0\cdot|L_\alpha|=|L_\alpha|=|\alpha|=|\alpha+1|$. For limit steps the proof is similar.

To see that $|R_\alpha|=\beth_{\omega+\alpha}$, use a similar induction and the definition of $\beth$ numbers.

Comment: ok, so the "equivalence" that is pointed in the problem is false, right

Comment: How do you figure? Also it seems to appear that no one is fully clear as for what is $R_\alpha$ exactly. It is a common notation for those whose von Neumann rank is $<\alpha$. If do you mean something else, let me know.

Comment: I mean that it´s neccesary to talk about the cardinality of alpha and not only alpha in the problem

Comment: If you're talking about cardinality of sets, it's not surprising that you need to talk about cardinal of things? In particular if it may or may not involve general ordinals. I still don't understand your first comment.

Comment: you are showing  |L α |=|α|  , is that incorrect that  |L α |=α ?

Comment: What does it mean $|L_\alpha|=\alpha$ if $\alpha$ is *not* a cardinal?

Comment: ok, sorry, now i understand all,